# How to get all records from Yesterday's date in Firestore Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch all the documents from Yesterday's date. Currently, I managed to get all the data from Today's date with the help of `where` and `isEqualTo` condition. But I'm not able to get the data from Yesterday's date.

Here is my code snippet from which I get Today's documents.

Thanks for the help.

```dart
final uid = getCurrentUID();

final QuerySnapshot result = await FirebaseFirestore
                              .instance
                              .collection('School')
                              .doc(uid)
                              .collection('School_Data')
                              .where('Todays_Date', isEqualTo: todaysDate)
                              .get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get both dates like this :

```
    DateTime todaysDate = DateTime.now();
    DateTime yesterdayDate = DateTime.utc(todaysDate.year, todaysDate.month, todaysDate.day -1);
```

If you want only the yesterday's data :

```
final QuerySnapshot result = await FirebaseFirestore
                              .instance
                              .collection('School')
                              .doc(uid)
                              .collection('School_Data')
                              .where('Todays_Date', isEqualTo: yesterdayDate)
                              .get();
```

If you want to get data since yesterday, Firestore allows you to perform range (<, <=, >, >=) or not equals (!=) comparisons on a single field :

```
final QuerySnapshot result = await FirebaseFirestore
                              .instance
                              .collection('School')
                              .doc(uid)
                              .collection('School_Data')
                              .where('Todays_Date', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: yesterdayDate)
                              .where('Todays_Date', isLessThanOrEqualTo: todaysDate)
                              .get();
```